# Git rebase while working on feature remote branch dilema

Tags: git, rebase, feature-branch

I have seen so many posts and blogs about `git` rebase on feature branch, but still confused 100%.

Scenario: I did the following steps while working on a newly created feature branch from master.

```
% git clone <repository>
% git checkout -b feature_branch origin/master
% git add .
% git commit -m "initial commit"
% git push
% git feature_branch [-u|--set-upstream-to]
% git checkout master
% git pull
% git rebase
% git checkout feature_branch
//make some changes locally
% git add .
% git commit 
% git push
```

At this stage I get message saying your remote branch is ahead of your local repository. Please pull first. When and how did the change into my remote feature branch occured?

I know here there is local repo of master and my feature branch and when I pull things they come from remote `origin/master`. So when I am making changes locally then my local feature_branch is ahead of remote feature_branch I assume.

Where could I be taking wrong steps in this context? What should be the actual steps for working on a initial local `feature_branch` which then goes to `remote` for backup in case something goes wrong while developing. I wanted to use `rebase` to keep the git history clean. Then what will be the steps? THe above as I mentioned?

Comment: Note that `git branch --set-upstream` is deprecated in modern Git: using it gets `fatal: the '--set-upstream' option is no longer supported. ...` Did you actually use `--set-upstream`, indicating you have an old Git, or did you use `--set-upstream-to`?

Comment: I guess I used `git branch [-u|--set-upstream-to]`

Comment: OK - so `feature_branch` now has `@{u}` coming out as ... what? (run `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name feature-branch@{u}` to find out)

Comment: Running that command shows `refs/remotes/origin/bugfix/feature_branch`

Comment: OK. I'm going to make one more assumption: that you actually ran `git push -u feature_branch` for the first `git push` above, because if your `push.default` is set to `simple`, a plain `git push` would give you an error about not having an upstream set. (Or maybe it did and that's why you set one?)

Comment: I only did `git push feature_branch`. Didn't use the `-u` flag initially. Then I got the recommendation. To be honest I don't remember the exact command. I just copied from the recommendation and executed it, which apparently pushed the changes by creating a remote branch for the `feature_branch` I was working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making several assumptions here; I'll note them.

Here is the sequence of commands, along with what I assume and what they then do:

> ```
> % git clone <repository>
> ```

I assume this works and you also then `cd` into the new clone (you didn't show this).

> ```
> % git checkout -b feature_branch origin/master
> ```

This creates, in your new local repository, a new branch name, `feature_branch`, that selects the same commit as `origin/master`.  The name `origin/master`—which is short for `refs/remotes/origin/master`—is not actually a *branch* name, but rather, is your Git's memory of their (`origin`'s) `master`, the last time your Git updated its own memory: in this case, at the time you ran `git clone`.

They may or may not already have a branch named `feature_branch` of their own!  You created *your* `feature_branch` locally.  If they do have a `feature_branch`, yours is not related to theirs, unless by some chance theirs is also exactly the same as their `master` (which is your `origin/master`).

> ```
> % git add .
> ```

This wouldn't do anything, since you have not modified any files, and all the files in your working tree came out of the commit.

> ```
> % git commit -m "initial commit"
> ```

This also would not do anything.  Your existing `feature_branch` is still even with their `master`, your `origin/master`.

If you did modify some files before `git add .` and `git commit`, this made one new commit on your `feature_branch`.

> % git push

This would give you an error, in a modern Git, along with a lot of advice suggesting `git branch --set-upstream-to` or `git push -u` or something along those lines:

> ```
> % git feature_branch [-u|--set-upstream-to]
> ```

This isn't a command.  If this was actually:

```
 git branch --set-upstream-to origin/feature_branch
```

*and* you got no *errors* here, that means they already had their own `feature_branch`.  This seems like the most likely issue here.

(If you actually ran, instead:

```
git push -u origin feature_branch
```

that would *create* a new name, `feature_branch`, over on the Git repository at `origin`, based on your `feature_branch`, and we probably would not see any errors later.)

> ```
> % git checkout master
> % git pull
> ```

There isn't really any point to doing these two, and they likely did nothing.  If they did do something, it will *generally* be harmless—though this depends on who is doing what with the Git repository over on `origin`.

> ```
> % git rebase
> ```

You are, at this point, still on your `master`, and it would again do nothing.

> ```
> % git checkout feature_branch
> //make some changes locally
> % git add .
> % git commit
> ```

Here, we finally get somewhere: we add a new commit, locally, to the local branch named `feature_branch`.  But if *they had their own feature branch*, your local branch and theirs have now diverged, and:

> ```
> % git push
> ```

this would complain that you need to use `git pull` or similar to accommodate their work.

What you probably want to do at this point is:

```
git rebase --onto origin/feature_branch origin/master
```

which will copy your one actually-new-commit that you've made on your `feature_branch`, that extends out from your `origin/master`.  The new-and-improved copy of that one commit will go after *their* last commit on *their* `feature_branch`, which is your `origin/feature_branch`.

As a drawing, we might have something that looks like this:

```
          K   <-- feature_branch (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/feature_branch
```

What this drawing *means* is:

1. Your current branch is `feature_branch`.  That's the special name `HEAD` here.
2. Your current *commit* is `K`.  The real hash ID of any commit is unique, but big and ugly and impossible for humans to deal with: it looks like random gibberish.  So when we make simplified drawings of what's going on in a repository, we are often well-served by substituting in simpler names for the commits.  So that's what I've done here.
3. Their `master` (your `origin/master`) and your `master` both select commit `H`.
4. Their `feature_branch`—your `origin/feature_branch`—selects some *later than `H`* commit `J`.

Note that I've drawn commits with later ones towards the right.  Each commit links backwards to an earlier commit, so commit `H` links backwards to some earlier commit `G`, which links backwards to earlier commits I did not bother to try to draw.  Meanwhile, commit `J` links backwards to `I`, which links backwards to `H`.

This sort of backwards linkage is what Git commits are really all about.  Every time you make a *new* commit, Git packages up a snapshot of every file, as of the form it has now (after `git add`-ing a copy into Git: the copies you can see and work on/with aren't actually *in* Git, which has invisible secret copies).  Git adds on *metadata*, such as your name and email address and the current date-and-time.  Git makes this metadata such that it includes the hash ID of the *current* commit—in this case, commit `K`—and writes all of that out to produce a new commit, which we can call `L`:

```
            L
           /
          K
         /
...--G--H
         \
          I--J
```

And now, as its last trick, `git commit` writes the raw hash ID of that commit into the *current branch name*, giving us:

```
          K--L   <-- feature_branch (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/feature_branch
```

I don't have to draw `L` on a separate line here as I don't need to draw in any arrows pointing to commit `K`, but if you'd made another branch name `temp` that pointed to `K`, I would leave `L` on a separate line:

```
            L   <-- feature_branch (HEAD)
           /
          K   <-- temp
         /
...--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/feature_branch
```

This is (intended to be) the same drawing, but with the addition of the name `temp`.

(You might want to run `git log --all --graph --decorate --oneline` or any of the other commands shown in the answers on [Pretty Git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452) to view other ways of looking at the set of commits you have.)

#### The point of `git rebase` is to *copy* commits

The good thing about a commit is that it can never be changed... at all.  You cannot change *anything* about an existing commit.  Not even Git itself can do that.

The bad thing about a commit is that it can never be changed.  Commit `K`—the one you made on your `feature_branch` back when you started with:

```
...--G--H   <-- master, origin/master, feature_branch (HEAD)
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/feature_branch
```

is stuck where it is, pointing backwards to existing commit `H`.  You might like everything *else* about it, but you don't like the fact that it points to `H`, because *their* latest `feature_branch` commit is commit `J`.  So you need a new and improved version of `K`.

The rebase command is about making these new and improved commits.  It can *copy* old commit `K` to a new and improved `K'`.  It then has your Git repository *abandon* the old `K` and use the new-and-improved `K'` instead.

The bad things about using rebase are:

- You have to be careful about how many commits it copies.  Sometimes the defaults are right, and sometimes they're not.
- Because it *copies* commits, anyone *else* who has the originals *also has to abandon the old ones for the new-and-improved ones.  This takes work on their part.

If you haven't given out the old ones, there's nobody else who *has* the old ones, so rebase is safe.  Otherwise, you need to tell whoever has them that you are doing this.

Anyway, given:

```
          K   <-- feature_branch (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/feature_branch
```

running:

```
git rebase --onto origin/feature_branch origin/master
```

tells your Git: *do copy `K`, stop copying at `H`, and put the copies after `J`*.

If your commit graph *is* the one I drew, a simpler rebase would have the same effect—but your commit graph might instead look like this:

```
          K   <-- feature_branch (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
      \
       I--J   <-- origin/feature_branch
```

In this case, the simpler command (that I'm still not showing) would try to copy `H` to a new and improved `H'`, which you don't want to do.

In both cases, *after* the rebase, your new and improved `K'` will come after `J`, e.g.:

```
          K   [abandoned]
         /
...--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/feature_branch
              \
               K'  <-- feature_branch (HEAD)
```

Since we—and Git—*find* commits by starting from the branch names, following the arrows to the commits, and then working *backwards* (leftwards in these drawings), nobody will ever see commit `K` again.  It's still there—nobody and nothing can change it—but it might as well be gone.

(Eventually—after a minimum of 30 days by default—Git will notice that nobody can *find* `K`, and strip it away for real, but you won't notice that either.)

Comment: This is an excellent explanation. I need a long time to read and understand it.  Great work.